# Error with javascript in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

I have a problem with JavaScript running in Firefox. The script below runs without a problem in other browsers except Firefox.

```
var vars = [], hash;
                var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

                for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
                {
                    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                    vars.push(hash[0]);
                    vars[hash[i]] = hash[1];
                }
                if (vars[0] != ' ')
                {
                    document.all['companyURL'].innerHTML = vars[0];
                    document.getElementById('domain').value = vars[0];
                }
```

So this code runs during page load and should grab the values after the URL and replace a line of text in the page with whatever is in the URL.

This is the line of text it needs to replace (yourcompany.com):

```
<h1><a href="" id="companyURL" name="companyURL">yourcompany.com</a> is available.<img src="images/checkmark_64.png" alt="check image"></h1>
```

So if the url is "google.com?hello.com", then the text in the page needs to change from "yourcompany.com" to "hello.com", but when the page loads in Firefox, it gives me the error "**document.all is undefined**" and points to the line of code with this in it.

```
document.all['companyURL'].innerHTML = vars[0];
```

I have no idea why this is happening and I can't find any information online that can help me correct the issue. Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.reloco.com.ar/mozilla/compat.html should be of some use to you--use getElementById() now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

replace:

```
document.all['companyURL'].innerHTML = vars[0];
```

with:

```
document.getElementById('companyURL').innerHTML = vars[0];
```

Answer (score 6):

document.all is not supported by mozilla/FF

you can just use `document.getElementById("companyURL")` there

Comment: To be more precise, document.all was invented by Microsoft and introduced with IE 4. Its problematic, since if a page has a field with name="ab" and an element with id="ab" which one would be found through document.all? try to avoid it like the plague.

Comment: More exactly, `document.all` is not supported by Firefox in Standards Mode at all, and in Quirks Mode, it has limited support, which does not include access to elements by `name` or `id` attribute.

Comment: Oops, in Quirks Mode, Firefox supports all of `document.all` except `document.all.tags()`. (I tested wrongly first.)

Answer (score 1):

document.all is an old IE4 standard. You should be using document.getElementById()

I would recommend you leverage one of the common javascript libraries that will abstract the different browsers implementations.