# Javascript calculator not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple area calculator for a landscaping company and it is only working in chrome, IE and Safari but not in firefox. Can someone show me what the issue could be? I figured it may be a js issue.

Here is a link to a working page: http://tinyurl.com/calc1test1

Here is the html:

```
  <h4><span>Area Calculator</span></h4>
                            <div class="boxInfo contactForm">

                                      <div style="display:none"><input type="checkbox"         name="CampaignList_64585" checked="checked" value="on" /></div>
                                     <div>
                                         <label>Length:</label>
                                        <input type=text name="square_length" size="3" onChange="get_cubicyards();">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Width:</label>
                                        <input type=text name="square_width" size="3" onChange="get_cubicyards();">
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Depth:</label>
                                         <input type=text name="square_depth" size="3" onChange="get_cubicyards();">
                                    </div>

                                <div class="calcbutton">

                                        <input id="contactSubmit" class="calcsubmit"  type="button" value="Get Amounts" onClick="get_cubicyards();">
                                </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <label>Cubic Yards:</label>
                                        <input type=text name="square_cuyard" onFocus="calculate_totals();this.blur();">
                                    </div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
 <script language="Javascript">
    function isValidInput(strString)
    {
        //String of valid characters
        var strValidChars = '0123456789.';
        var strChar;
        var blnResult = true;
        var decimalCount = 0;

        if (strString.length == 0) return false;

        //Test strString consists of valid characters listed above
        for (i = 0; i < strString.length && blnResult == true; i++)
        {   strChar = strString.charAt(i);
            if (strValidChars.indexOf(strChar) == -1)
            {   blnResult = false; }
            if (strChar == '.')
            { decimalCount++; }
        }

        if (decimalCount > 1)
        { blnResult = false; }

        return blnResult;
    }

    function get_cubicyards()
    {   var cubicyards;

                if(  (eval('document.all.square_depth.value')) && (!isValidInput(eval('document.all.square_depth.value')))  )
                {   alert('You must enter only numeric values.'); 
                    eval('document.all.square_cuyard.value = \'\'');
                    return false; 
                }
                if(  (eval('document.all.square_length.value')) && (!isValidInput(eval('document.all.square_length.value')))  )
                {   alert('You must enter only numeric values.');                   
                    eval('document.all.square_cuyard.value = \'\'');
                    return false; 
                }
                if(  (eval('document.all.square_width.value')) && (!isValidInput(eval('document.all.square_width.value')))  )
                {   alert('You must enter only numeric values.'); 
                    eval('document.all.square_cuyard.value = \'\'');
                    return false; 
                }

                //Only make calculations if there are valid values specified for ALL necessary fields
                if (  (eval('document.all.square_depth.value')) && (eval('document.all.square_length.value')) && (eval('document.all.square_width.value'))  )
                {   cubicyards = (eval('(document.all.square_depth.value * document.all.square_length.value * document.all.square_width.value)/324')*1000)/1000;
                    eval('document.all.square_cuyard.value = '+cubicyards);
                    return true;
                }


    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you use `eval`?

Comment: Did you even check the console? `TypeError: document.all is undefined`. Duplicate solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820440/error-with-javascript-in-firefox

Comment: You'll probably be better off using jQuery instead of relying on Browser specific properties like `document.all`. Also `eval` is evil, so beware :) http://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil/

Answer (score 2):

You are using document.all this is not in the w3c standard. you can add an id to the input fields and then get their values using the w3c standard:

```
document.getElementById('[id name here]')
```

Answer (score 0):

`if( (eval('document.all.square_depth.value')) && (!isValidInput(eval('document.all.square_depth.value'))) )`

The quick answer is that Firefox doesn't support [`document.all`](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2005/08/firefox-documentall-caveat.html).

But, um, the long answer is that this code isn't complete.  You might want to insert `form` tags so that you can do crossbrowser code like...

```
<form name='myForm'>
    <h4>Area Calculator</h4>
    <div class="boxInfo contactForm">
        <div style="display:none"><input type="checkbox" name="CampaignList_64585" checked="checked" value="on" /></div>
        <div>
            <label>Length:</label>
            <input type="text" name="square_length" size="3" onchange="get_cubicyards();">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Width:</label>
            <input type="text" name="square_width" size="3" onchange="get_cubicyards();">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Depth:</label>
            <input type="text" name="square_depth" size="3" onchange="get_cubicyards();">
        </div>
        <div class="calcbutton">
            <input id="contactSubmit" class="calcsubmit" type="button" value="Get Amounts" onclick="get_cubicyards();">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Cubic Yards:</label>
            <input type="text" name="square_cuyard" onfocus="calculate_totals();this.blur();">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

...

```
function get_cubicyards() { 
    var cubicyards,
        myForm = document.forms['myForm'];

    if (isNaN(myForm.elements['square_length'].value ))    {
        alert('You must enter only numeric values.'); 
    } else {
        // ... more checks and logic                
    } 
}
```

Honestly, with the crossbrowser **un**-friendly code, this strange `eval` usage others have pointed out, no [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), potential `div` overkill, a gratuitous `span` nested in `h4`, etc, you're probably going to really benefit from slowing down and following a few introductory tutorials ([this one](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) isn't great, but is a start) before asking too many questions.

We all start somewhere!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox console shows this error:

```
[10:26:13.365] TypeError: document.all is undefined @ http://kynock.wildwingdesign.com/calctest:72
```

You can't use `document.all` in Firefox.  The real issue here is that your javascript is REALLY poorly conceived.  There should be no need for `eval()` here and there should be now need for `document.all`. Simply give each of your inputs an `id` value and use `documentGetElementById('yourId').value` to get the values stored in the inputs.